# Success and error messages are not displaying after migrating to 2.4.3 p1 EE in admin panel magento2

Tags: magento2

Success and error messages are not displaying after migrating to 2.4.3 p1 EE in admin panel magento2

Could anyone please suggest me workarround

Comment: Hi Team,Any help on this?

Answer (score 0):

We faced same issue after upgrade Magento2 EE to 2.4.3-p1.
Solve by set **Max Session Size in Admin = 0**